# What do the anglo-saxons use as "soggettario"?

Tags: library

A [soggettario](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soggettario) (in Italian) is simply a list of [subject headings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_heading): it's a kind of thesaurus, used both as manual/tool for cataloguing and for browsing subjects and finding all books in a certain subject within the catalogue.

For instance the [LCSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_of_Congress_Subject_Headings) or the [Nuovo soggettario](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuovo_soggettario). I can [search a topic](http://thes.bncf.firenze.sbn.it/ricerca_eng.php?menuR=2&menuS=2&lang=en&tiporicerca=partedi&terminericerca=universit%C3%A0), browse the hierarchy and [end up in the OPAC](http://opac.bncf.firenze.sbn.it/opac/controller.jsp?action=search_multiplasearch&query_fieldname_3=soggettokw&query_querystring_3=%22Istruzione%20superiore%22&Submit=Esegui+ricerca&lang=en) listing the titles.

So, does this whole thing have a single name in English? Do you use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it may be more suitable on English SE.

Comment: I don't know... it's about what people use for this procedure. The English name might not be a direct translation. It's not a matter of linguistics but of reference.

Comment: If you are refering to a list (or database) of keywords the correct term would be Search Index, or simply Index

Comment: I believe the topic fits the community, because it is about the functioning of research facilities (such as libraries and databases). I strongly believe that AcademiaSE should host these topics. 

Nevertheless, this particular question is more about the english language itself: the english term for the italian "soggettario" is "Subject Headings List", or "Subject Index". This is a simple matter of translation.

Comment: To be more accurate, the "Soggettario" is not just a list of terms (thesaurus) or subject entries. It is actually a manual containing the rules to create and organize the subject headings. A proper translation would be "Subject Indexing Tool", as expressed for example here: http://thes.bncf.firenze.sbn.it/index_eng.html

In the same way, the France National Library uses the term "Indexation Matière" (lit. Subject Indexing): http://www.bnf.fr/fr/professionnels/anx_catalogage_indexation/a.referentiels_sujet.html